# Performing Reflection-like Operations with Managed VC++  on Unmanaged C++

Tags: visual-c++, reflection, rtti

I have a managed VC++ where I would like to do things like `Type::GetMembers()` and `PropertyInfo::GetValue()` on unmanaged C++.

I read a little about the [Unmanaged Reflection API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk4hw0yf.aspx) but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

Thanks.

Comment: No, the compiler doesn't generate any metadata for native code.  The unmanaged reflection api is available to give native code access to the metadata for a managed program.  Useful when writing compilers and somesuch.

Comment: @Hans: The compiler generates metadata if you pass [`/Zi`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/958x11bc.aspx) -- "Produces a program database (PDB) that contains type information"

Answer (score 0):

You're looking in completely the wrong place.

A native debugger is the most common tool that performs these operations, the necessary metadata is stored in the debug database (.pdb file for Visual C++).

[The native debugging APIs are extensively documented.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663265.aspx)

For example, [`SymGetTypeInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681349.aspx) (and the newer [`SymGetTypeInfoEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681350.aspx)) gives access to information roughly equivalent to that found in `System.Type`, including base classes, members, etc.